# Different Permastruck Between Ajax Request & Normal Request

Tags: permalinks

i create new post type and the slug can be changed from backend ex:

```
register_post_type( 'job', array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => $slug
    );
));
```

`$slug` is variable that i take from backend. and its working fine if im doing normal request. i get right URL using `get_permalink` function.

but the problem arise when i doing ajax request. i dive into the code, and i get normal request and ajax request return different result of permastruck.

on normal request, its return right result of permastruck for example :

```
[job] => Array
    (
        [with_front] => 1
        [ep_mask] => 1
        [paged] => 1
        [feed] => 
        [forcomments] => 
        [walk_dirs] => 1
        [endpoints] => 1
        [struct] => /lowongan-kerja/%job%
    )
```

and the URL result look like this :  `http://localhost/lowongan-kerja/programmer/`

but on ajax, its returning different permastruck :

```
[job] => Array
    (
        [with_front] => 1
        [ep_mask] => 1
        [paged] => 1
        [feed] => 
        [forcomments] => 
        [walk_dirs] => 1
        [endpoints] => 1
        [struct] => /job/%job%
    )
```

and very weird, the URL look like this : `http://localhost/job/programmer/`

how can i make both on normal & ajax request having the same URL?

Comment: do you register your post type on the `init` action?

Comment: Yes i do. `add_action('init', array(&$this, 'register_post_type'));`

Comment: without seeing your code in its entirety it's difficult to say what the issue may be. this is certainly not normal behavior, and should work without having to add an additional permastruct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i examine several plugin to learn how it work and find solution by using add_permastruct

```
add_permastruct( 'job', '/' . $slug . '/%job%', array(
            'with_front'  => false,
            'ep_mask'     => EP_NONE,
            'paged'       => false,
            'feed'        => false,
            'forcomments' => false,
            'walk_dirs'   => true,
            'endpoints'   => false,
        ));
```

and the problem is solved :)